# Does CIDR (Classless inter-domain routing) generate same IP adresses?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I already understand CIDR split the IP into the network prefix part and host part.
But what confuses me is that users can divide an IP block privately to build different sub-nets by themselves.
For example:

Company A get an IP block of `135.64.128.0/17`

Company B get an IP block of `135.64.192.0/18`

Company A decides to build different sub-nets in different departments, so instead of `135.64.128.0/17`, department A-1 get `135.64.128.0/18`, department A-2 get `135.64.192.0/18`.

Question: Department A-2 now have `135.64.192.0/18`, identical to company B. Will this make IP conflicts? Or something's originally wrong that this will never happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Company A got `135.64.128.0/17`, then Company B cannot get
`135.64.192.0/18`.

This is because the block for Company A would then include Company B.
No intersection is possible when allocating IP blocks.

Only if Company B is a sub-company of A, then A can allocate it
this slice. But this decision is internal to Company A.
For the rest of the world, Company A stays the
sole owner of `135.64.128.0/17`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why CIDR is just a temporary approach, it's kind of limited.